# How to get git to stop ignoring one folder

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, gitignore

I have a programming project in Visual Studio and i use the Git with it. The Visual Studio automatically generated a .gitignore file in my project's main folder.

This is the part that ignores the bin folder, which contains my compiled project in debug and release folders:

```
# Build results

[Dd]ebug/
x64/
build/
[Bb]in/
[Rr]elease/
[Oo]bj/
```

The folder structure looks like this:

```
root/
   .git/
   .gitignore
   file.doc
   Myproject/
       somefile.txt
       bin/
           Debug/
               filefoo.bar
           Release/
               someotherfile.exe
```

I want the git to ignore everything in the bin folder, except the Release folder.

I tried both to remove the `[Rr]elease/` line and to change it to `![Rr]elease/` but none of that seems to work.

Comment: Try `![bB]in/[Rr]elease/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's enough to just `git add` the files you want, and they won't be ignored, no matter what `.gitignore` says.

The ignore rules only apply to "untracked" files. That is, files git does not have in its repository. Once you add a file, it is no longer untracked, and the ignore rules won't apply.

However, `git add` itself won't automatically add ignored files when you tell it to add a directory tree, so you must check carefully that you did add everything you meant to.

Comment: Yes that worked, i did git `add Myproject/bin/Release -f` (had to use -f to override ignoring rule). But when i checked the .gitignore file it hasn't been changed. Where is that new rule saved then?

Comment: It doesn't modify the `.gitignore`, or write any "rules". It's just that tracked files are never ignored.

Comment: Please note that this will only add the files present in the directory at the time when you add them. If later on you get more files in the Release directory, git will still ignore those until you explicitly add them, meaning that you won't even get a note in status lists that you have untracked files there.

Comment: Side-question: Why on earth are you committing build output to your repository in the first place?

Comment: It contains some dlls necessary for my application to run so when someone pulls from the github he won't be missing those dlls.